# Copy list of array multidimension python 3

Tags: python, list

In my case I had array list of:

```
testSet =[[14017.0, 146.58, 5.0, '1'], [3869.0, 91.66, 5.0, '1'], [9365.0, 131.16, 5.0, '1'], [1258.0, 62.8, 5.0, '1'], [2979.0, 95.9, 4.0, '1'], [5556.0, 109.4, 5.0, '1'], [14501.0, 144.0, 5.0, '1'], [3664.0, 106.5, 5.0, '1'], [6149.0, 117.6, 2.0, '2'], [5556.0, 109.4, 5.0, 2']]
```

I just wanna copy the last element in every array to my new array. How to copy that array so I can get output:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
```

Comment: list, i dont use numpy

Comment: yes, iam sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you list comprehension and you are good to go.

```
new = [array[-1] for array in testSet]
```

Complexity is just **O(n)** where n is the length of your testSet.